# SQL: Delete all rows except

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I want to remove all rows where:

```
 DELETE FROM `users logins` WHERE `userid` = '$user->id'
```

However, I want to prevent the row being deleted if `token = $user->token`

I'm building a reset password function and once a password is rest I need to logout the user from all their devices, all but the one they're on.

Is this possible with a single SQL statement?

Comment: `Is this possible with a single SQL statement?` yes. BTW: this should have been an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it on the condition

```
DELETE FROM `users logins` 
WHERE `userid` = '$user->id' AND
      `token` <> '$user->token'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM `users logins` 
    WHERE `userid` = '$user->id' AND
          `token` != '$user->token'
```